# How to convert XML files to PDF files?

Tags: xml-parsing

I want to convert different XML files to PDF

Is necessary convert to HTML first or can I convert it directly?

Comment: Do oyu want to write your own program or do you want a program that already exist?

Comment: I'm in investigation stage, I want to see my option, I want to see programs that already exist and I want to know if is possible do the conversion directly in a programmable way

Comment: For programs that already exist a quick google search on "convert XML to PDF" got me a lot of relevant hits